# "Союзная республика": нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Бывшая «союзная республика» - нужны кавычки?

Answer (score 2):

Контекст дайте. Я совсем не уверен, что здесь именно прямое значение.

Comment: Слова *"бывшая"* вполне хватает, чтобы понять, о чем идет речь.

Comment: @Валентин, от контекста зависит.

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь, что этот вопрос касается подчеркивания политических взглядов средствами синтаксиса.

Скажем, коммунист напишет "союзные республики" без кавычек, а "западные демократии" - в кавычках и наоборот. Только пишущий знает, что для него - "так называемое", а о чём он пишет в прямом смысле.

Если взгляды не выпячиваются, то и кавычки не используются.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что можно выпятить в названии "союзная республика", пусть и бывшая. Ведь это, в отличии от "демократии" - юридический термин.

Comment: Поскольку попикстартер не ответил, похоже, он действительно что-то не выпячивал, но вкладывал. )))

Comment: @Docent: Вон behemothus правильно говорит – вкладывал автор... 

Вкладывал, я полагаю, своё недопонимание: что же это за союзные республики были, если Союз Нерушимый, который из них состоял, развалился? Некондиционные, туды их в качель! В смысле, в кавычки.  

Политика-с... Ещё 25 лет назад никто бы таким вопросом и не задался. Никаких кавычек у союзных республик не могло быть в принципе.  

Как там у А.Толстого в "Петре I" князя Лыкова оскорбляли: "ты прежде был князь, а ныне ты - небылица". Вот так и с этим юридическим термином.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, кавычки не нужны, ведь здесь слова "союзная республика" употреблены в прямом значении